# Correct regex for matching EXACTLY n instances of a pattern

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following:

```
1.) /some/text/here/with-dashes/010101/
2.) /some/text/here/too/
3.) /some/other/really-long/text/goes/here/019293847/
```

I want to get the strings that contains EXACTLY 6 `/` so far these regex aren't working how I intended it to:

```
(/\w+[-]?\w+){6}
(/\w+[-]?\w+){6,6}
(/\w+[-]?\w+){,6}?
```

These regex also matches strings with more than 6 `/` I want it to match strings with EXACTLY 6 `/`.

Comment: Do you really need regexes? You could just `parts = path.split("/")`...

Comment: @Kroltan I am using regex in combination with beautifulsoup to filter out url. Something like soup.find("a", href = regex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for exactly six matches is `{6}` as in your first example.

The reason that the regexes you're using are matching more than six occurrences of your target string is that they aren't anchored to the beginning and end of the string. If a string has (say) ten occurrences of path components, it matches the first six, so that counts.

To fix this, use e.g.:

```
^(/\w+[-]?\w+){6}$
```

Or to allow an optional closing slash:

```
^(/\w+[-]?\w+){6}/?$
```

Comment: so by adding `^` and `$` in the regex, it basically means that entire string must contain EXACTLY 6 occurences?

Comment: It actually means that "those six ocurrences must happen over the whole string", but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`more_itertools.exactly_n`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.exactly_n) a third-party library.

**Code**

```
iterable = "1.) /some/text/here/with-dashes/010101/"
pred = lambda x: x == "/"
n = 6

mit.exactly_n(iterable, n, pred)
# True
```

---

**Tests**

```
f = mit.exactly_n

assert f("1.) /some/text/here/with-dashes/010101/", n, pred) == True
assert f("2.) /some/text/here/too/", n, pred) == False
assert f("3.) /some/other/really-long/text/goes/here/019293847/", n, pred) == False
```